# What if some people use Stack Overflow as Google

Tags: discussion, questions, users, question-quality

Many times while answering questions I see questions where people post questions **without even googling** for the same thing, while the **first link gives their answer**.

Even people do not pay attention to the similar questions already posted on the site.

Some users continuously do the same. So is there a way to solve this?

**UPDATE:** Can there be a separate **flag** indicating a lack of proper searching, so that when some user continuously does the same thing, some appropriate steps can be taken for the same?

Comment: In their defense, they may have accidentally Binged first and did not find anything useful. You tend to see folks complain about not finding anything on MSDN...only to discover they use Bing and not Google. Dollars to donuts though, I'll bet I could flag to close EVERY question with that reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  Their questions will (usually) be heavily downvoted due to the very clear lack of research.  Eventually the automatic question ban will kick in preventing them from asking new questions.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: @NarendraPathai Why would you need a flag.  There is no need for moderator intervention.  You don't need a mod to downvote.  You don't need a mod to vote to close a post that should be closed (you can flag to close if you don't have 3k rep though).  Many of these types of posts are either duplicates, NARQ, or too localized (not all though).  What are you expecting a mod to do in response to a flag like this?

Comment: Yes i agree if the automatic question ban does kick in then it would not be required. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Some users continuously do the same. So is there a way to solve this?

Yes: do not be ashamed to downvote and closevote when you see this.

If you can, and it's a user who is new to the site, accompany your vote with a polite comment. I usually post something like this:

> Hi, please always remember to Google first. Searching for `xyz` gives me this resource, which will answer all your questions: ..... Also, there are plenty of existing questions about this on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, easily Googleable questions here are OK, but we only need **one** of each.

When telling people to "Google it", *very* often the first few results return a link to the very question asked! I've seen this happen *many* times.

If the question is decent, the best thing to do in my opinion is close it as a duplicate (if it's just *way* too basic, I usually close as "too localized"). Ironically, the easiest way to find duplicates is usually Google.

We don't need a new flag for this, it's something the community can handle without direct moderator intervention (which is what flags are for).

Comment: You are absolutely right in principle, but there are so many of these coming in, dupe-searching gets tiring eventually. It really feels like doing the OP's job for them.

Comment: I agree with Wesley. Ultimately we want SO to be a resource for finding answers, so when someone goes to google, they get directed *to* SO. That being said a lot of questions being asked are dupes... I work in the `javascript` tag and I swear 70% of questions asked there are asked by new users with 1 point and are dupes of old questions... So I guess I agree with @Pekka웃 as well...

Comment: @ryan yeah. That's why the argument can be made that it's *necessary* to downvote these dupes and not answer them - questions with negative votes and no answers get removed over time, and stop cluttering the search index.

Answer (score 2):

There *should not* be a separate flag for "insufficient searching".

The reason is simple: outside of a few very special case scenarios, I likely could find something somewhere which makes your question "searchable" and thus flaggable. With six 9's of certainty every question is boring and has been rehashed a million times over in some way, shape, or form.

Furthermore, flags are not for *technical problems*, flags are for problems which only a moderator could handle.

We already have effective tools in place to combat these poorly researched questions:

1. Downvotes
2. Votes to close

Answer (score 0):

> Can there be a separate **flag** indicating a lack of proper searching, so that when some user continuously does the same thing, some appropriate steps can be taken for the same?

There is nothing the moderators can do, except in the case the question needs to be closed, or the question is spam. As for those cases, there is already a specific flag (for those who cannot vote to close, in the first case), there isn't the need to have yet another flag for handling a case that is already handled.